# Is a transformation of a conditional distribution identical to the conditional of the transformation?

Tags: probability, distributions

## Problem

Say that we can find a random vector $(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n)$ whose distribution is identical to the conditional distribution of $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ under $f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1$, where $f(\cdot)$ is some function.

$$(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n) \overset{d}{\equiv} (X_1, \cdots, X_n) \Big|  f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1 $$

Now say we have been given $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ : $1$-to-$1$ function.

---

### Question

> Is is true that
>   $$
> g(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n)  \overset{d}{\equiv} g(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \Big|  f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1 
> $$?

---

### Try

Answering the above question is equivalent to showing the following

$$
g\left( (X_1, \cdots, X_n) \Big|  f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1 \right) \overset{d}{\equiv} g (X_1, \cdots, X_n) \Big|  f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1
$$

since by definition $g(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n)  \overset{d}{\equiv} g\left( (X_1, \cdots, X_n) \Big|  f(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \le 1 \right)$.

But I'm not sure how it can be rigorously shown.

Any help will be appreciated.